# Difference between the usage of "out" and "outside"?

Tags: meaning

> He is standing out or outside.
>   Someone is shouting outside.
>   It is raining out or outside.

Comment: Please describe more about your situation. Where is the location of the person in question?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Sharma. We expect people to do a bit of research before they ask a question, then to quote this research in their question. They can then ask specific questions about things that they don't understand in the information that they have found. Here is some information about how to write a good question http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please. In this case, I suggest that you look up out and outside in a good dictionary like this one, http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out, and have a look at the example sentences.

Answer (score 2):

**outside** generally refers to not being in a building, cave, or other enclosed area. If you are outside generally you can see the sky (unless you are under a tree, bridge, or the like.) Out is more generic and just refers to not being in.

"the dog crawled out" means the dog came out of something, this could be a house, a room, from under the bed, etc.
"the dog crawled outside" specifically refers to the dog leaving a building (or other such thing). Or, if the dog is already not inside of a building(etc.), then outside is the location that the dog is crawling, basically it is crawling outside of buildings where it can see the sky.

I hope that made sense, it is somewhat hard to describe.

Answer (score 0):

"outside" is a location relative to where you are (presumably, you are inside), so in all three of your samples, 'outside' is the normal choice.

"out" is usually directional, So your 'It is raining out' would be probably understood as it is raining inside but some of it is leaking through the walls / windows to the outside world (this is far less likely to happen in practice than 'It is raining in').

A less common use of "out" would be as a comparator; as in "He stood out from the crowd", meaning he was different from the rest of the people even if physically located amongst them.